# Auto Initialization of local variables

Tags: c, variables, scope, initialization

I have the following code snippet.

```
int j;
printf("%d",j);
```

As expected, I get a garbage value.

> 32039491

But when I include a loop in the above snippet, like

```
int j;
print("%d",j);
while(j);
```

I get the following output on multiple trials of the program.

> 0

I always thought local variables are initialized to a garbage value by default, but it looks like variables get auto initialized when a loop is used.

Comment: I am using VC++ 6.0 IDE and compiler and I don't get different results.

Comment: Garbage values are by their definition garbage. You can't rely on them having a certain value.

Comment: A gargabe value can be anything included 0.

Answer (score 8):

It is having **indeterminate value**. It can be anything.

Quoting `C11` §6.7.9

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
>   indeterminate. [...]

Automatic local variables, unless initialized explicitly, will contain indeterminate value. In case you try to use a variable while it holds indeterminate value and either

- does not have the address taken
- can have trap representation

the usage will lead to  [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: If the variables in the OPs code have automatic storage duration (which we can't tell), accessing them is undefined behavior, but not because of trap representations. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/why-is-using-an-uninitialized-variable-undefined-behavior-in-c/40674888#40674888).

Comment: @Lundin Thanks for the pointer sir, updated my answer, is it better now?

Answer (score 4):

> As expected, I get a garbage value.

Then your expectation is unjustifiably hopeful.  When you use the indeterminate value of an uninitialized object, you generally get (and for your code snippets alone you *do* get) **undefined behavior**.  Printing a garbage value is but one of infinitely many possible manifestations.

> I always thought local variables are initialized to a garbage value by default, but it looks like variables get auto initialized when a loop is used.

You thought wrong, and you're also drawing the wrong conclusion.  Both of your code snippets, when standing alone, exhibit undefined behavior.  You cannot safely rely on any particular result.

Comment: You can't know that it is undefined behavior because we can't tell the scope based on the OPs code. Similarly, you can't assume that the OP is using a system with trap representations. Therefore this is possibly incorrect: "When you use the indeterminate value of an uninitialized object, you get undefined behavior". [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/why-is-using-an-uninitialized-variable-undefined-behavior-in-c/40674888#40674888).

Comment: @Lundin, thanks for pointing that out.  I have qualified the answer a bit to allow myself what I think is sufficient weasel room.  Anyone interested in why I do so (i.e. the details of when the behavior is not undefined) can follow the link you kindly provided.